# Why tap water doesn' instantly form crystals when you shake it after cooling it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nucleation

For the science fair I am doing the experiment about nucleation in which I put a bottle of water in the freezer and after one hour and a half I take it out and it is supposed to instantly freeze when I shake it or pour it on ice, but my experiment doesn't work. I was doing my experiment with tap water, and my bottles were recycling bottles without a cap.   I have watched some videos and they use bottled water of different brands. It works only with some brands. Apparently, it works only with the purest waters. 
When I pour the water nothing happens and when I shake the bottle, some ice forms, but it doesn't happen as I see in the videos. I want to understand why. Please notice that I am eleven years old and my English level is not that of a native...

Comment: Tap water in your area might not be pure enough.

Comment: Tap water is usually not pure, but has chlorine and other chemicals in it, and this is basically true all over the world. If the water is not pure, then it will freeze inside the freezer. If the water does not freeze inside the fridge and does not freeze after shaking, I suspect that the temperature is not low enough. Did you checked that the freezer temperature goes below 0 Celsius?

Comment: So if it begins to freeze in the freezer the crystallization won't happen?

Answer (score 1):

One hour is not enough time to freeze a bottle of water. do this first: put a bottle of water in the freezer WITH A THERMOMETER IN IT. Read the temperature every 10 minutes until you KNOW the bottle is below freezing. Now repeat your original experiment without the thermometer, letting the bottle stay in the freezer for the same amount of time it took to go below freezing in your experiment.

I did this same experiment years ago as an engineer, studying the freeze behavior of a component with water in it. The components refused to freeze in my freezer no matter how long I left them in there! When pulling a rack full of them out of the freezer I accidentally dropped them onto the concrete floor and when they struck the floor, they all froze instantly!

Comment: Thank you for the idea about the thermometer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the entire amount of water to almost the freezing point, if it is right in front of the fan in the center of the freezer, it will cool too fast. Ice will form around the edges while the center is above freezing. try putting your bottle in a paper bag to insulate it some, and set it to the side of the freezer, maybe behind other frozen goods so it will cool slower and more evenly. Try leaving it in the freezer longer amounts of time. I like to do this with sugar free sports drinks, they work quite well, I cool them slowly in the freezer as I have said and try to get them just before they freeze. sometimes when you move them they will turn to slush before your eyes, then you can drink a very cold "slushy". But they have small amounts of salts and other additives. And if pouring over ice, make sure the ice is as far below freezing as possible, ice that is barely below freezing will not work as well.

Comment: So probably this was what happened. I saw some ice forming on top, and probably the rest of the water was warmer.

Answer (score 0):

As it may be expected, below a certain temperature, the solid state is thermodynamically favorable over the liquid state.  Yet the solidification of *liquid* water (of $0^\circ\mathrm{C}$) into solid water (ice) of the same temperature liberates the latent heat of crystallization.  Indeed, if you follow the crystallization of water carefully with a better thermometer (scaling $0.1^\circ\mathrm{C}$ or finer, e.g., classical [Beckmann thermometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beckmann_thermometer) or better electric ones) in calorimeters) you will observe a noticeable *increase* of temperature during the solidifcation. I can assure you -- from own experience -- the corresponding experiment in the lab class was, *despite* knowing about the facts by the previous lecture, revealing to all of us students; because tracing the temperature curve yielded a *sudden* peak in the otherwise descending slope.

In the case of water, this enthalpy equals to $(1.7 \pm 0.5)\,\mathrm{kJ/mol}$ [(reference)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0009261485871384).

Despite *thermodynamically favorable*, however, the process of crystallization need not yet occur if the kinetic barrier is just high enough.  This contributes to why we observe supercooled melts -- for example some types of honey we purchase liquid and that over time eventually solidify.